# Play multidomain intellij not runnable

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.5

I have cloned the template from here

https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-multidomain-auth#master

and I do the following

Steps:

1. Import into intellij with auto-import enabled
2. Run admin module -> it works
3. Close Intellij
4. Ropen Intellij
5. Run admin module -> it does not work.

I think it is a bug from Intellij or the scala plugin as the project does run with activator. The error I get is:

> /Users/git/sample/modules/admin/build.sbt:1: error: not found: value Common
>
> Common.moduleSettings("admin") ^ [error] Type error in expression

And it is because Intellij is auto-generating a project folder inside the admin module, thus the parent project folder is not visible. From the sbt reference
http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Multi-Project.html:

> You cannot have a project subdirectory or project/*.scala files in the
>   sub-projects. foo/project/Build.scala would be ignored.

I have spent hours on this and cant seem to find the magic config that makes intellij not auto generate modules/admin/project directory

If I do

```
activator ";project admin;~run"
```

the project runs perfectly

Comment: Question: How do you run the admin module form IntelliJ?
Comment: IntelliJ does not create any project directory. It's possible that sbt does this if you import only one module as project instead of importing the root project, because IntelliJ runs sbt for importing. Either way, if it exists it shouldn't matter, since it is ignored.
That said, I can reproduce the actual compile error in IntelliJ, and also witness highlighting errors that seem to be related to this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7237

Comment: I created an issue for this problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11291

Comment: I do the following:  From the main menu, select Run -> Edit Configurations
Click on the + to add a new configuration, chose play 2 app. Under Play2 Module: select admin module. Click apply, ok, and then run

Comment: Thanks, reproduced. Looks like a problem we'll have to address. Please follow the YouTrack issue for updates.

Comment: I may have another bug for you: Delete the target directory of the web module, right click on the web module and select build you will get 2 compile errors which are wrong because it actually compiles with both sbt and activator.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in IntelliJ-Scala 2017.1: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11291